# Do zombie villagers spawn less often in deserts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to repopulate an empty village by curing zombie villagers. The village is in the desert, so most of the zombies that spawn are husks. What's not clear to me is whether zombie villagers spawn in deserts at the same rate as in other biomes. The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie) contradicts itself on this point. At one point, it says:

> In desert biomes, all zombies exposed to the sky will have an 80% chance to be replaced by husks, a zombie variant. Zombies that are not husks have a 5% chance to spawn as a zombie villager while all zombie variants also have a 5% chance to spawn as a baby zombie type.

This would seem to suggest that only 1 percent of all zombies in desert biomes will spawn as villagers. However, later on the page it says simply that

> Zombie villagers comprise 5% of all spawned zombies.

I've tried to figure out which is correct for myself, but zombie villagers have been laughably scarce for me in all biomes ever since I commenced Operation Repopulation, so I can't tell whether they're really not there in the desert, or if I'm just getting unlucky. Does anyone know which statement from the wiki is correct?

Comment: From what I can tell, the 5% figure has been on the page since 2012, so won't be taking husks into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer is correct. Pseudo-code for what's actually going on when the zombie spawns:

```
if (biome is desert) and (has sky access from spawn point) and (80% chance) 
    spawn Husk
else if (5% chance)
    spawn Zombie Villager
else
    spawn Zombie
```

That means it is a 1% chance *if it has sky access*, so if you want villagers you should make a dark, underground room.

Comment: Extending out from PPCG, I see... Nice answer!